# What does this mean: ((Wrench)wrench).printInfo();

Tags: java, class, object, methods

Understanding that is crucial right now and I can't seem to find info anywhere and it's kind of impossible to google with the brackets on it.

There is a printInfo method in the code and a Wrench class, but what's with the  " ((Class)object).method(); "

Comment: It is a class cast. Read the [Java tutorial section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on Maciej's answer... in Java, the set of methods and fields you have access to depends on type a variable is *declared as* – not the type of the object it's actually *referencing* at any given point in time (which could be a subclass of that declared type). To access members of the subclass, you need to tell Java the subclass whose members you want to get at. And the way you do that is via a cast operator: `(Class)object`.

This is called a "downcast," meaning you're going from a superclass type to a subclass type. A downcast will throw a `ClassCastException` if the object is not actually of the right type .

So in Maciej's example above, `a` is a reference declared as type `A`. Its current value is an object of type `B`, but to get at `B`'s members you need to downcast from the reference of type `A` to a reference of type `B`.

About the extra parentheses: because of operator precedence, you can't just do `(Class)object.foo()` – Java will interpret it as `(Class)(object.foo())`. So you'll typically add parentheses to ensure the cast happens *before* the attemt to call `foo()`.

Answer (score 1):

Its called Casting
Take a look at this

```
public class A {
  //statements
}

public class B extends A {
  public void foo() { }
}

A a=new B();

//To execute **foo()** method.

((B)a).foo();
```